# The way to prove that a polynomial is irreducible

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Given:

> $x^3 + 2 \in \mathbb F_7[x]$ we have to prove that it is irreducible.

Now, in finite fields, to prove that a polynomial is irreducible, is it enough to show that it has no roots within $\mathbb F_7[x]$?

Comment: What is a "detachable" polynmomial??

Comment: When you write "not detachable", do you mean "irreducible"? When you write "final", do you mean "finite"?

Comment: What Gerry said.
Sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not for all polynomials. But for polynomials of degree $2$ or $3$, if it is reducible then it must have a root in the base field.

Comment: Thank you!
What do we do if it is not of degree $2$ or $3?

Comment: And for polynomials of degrees 2 and 3, it doesn't matter whether the field is finite or not.

Comment: @TheNotMe: To determine whether a general polynomial is irreducible you can use the factorization algorithms over finite field to factor it completely.

Comment: Thank you all so much for the wonderful information.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Yeah but if the field is finite the it can be easily checked whether the polynomial has a root.

Comment: If the field has $2^{1000}$ elements, it may not be so easy to check whether the polynomial has a root. On the other hand, if the field is the rationals, and the first and last coefficients aren't too big, it's easy to check whether the polynomial has a root.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if a cubic polynomial factors, one of the factors must be linear. In a field, setting that linear factor to be zero gives you a field element which is a root of the original equation.

When you go up to degree 4, a quartic can be the product of two irreducible quadratic factors, neither of which yield a root in the ground field.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

(1) A polynomial of degree up to three is irreducible over some field iff it has not roots in that field

(2) $\,\alpha^3\neq 5=-2\pmod 7\;,\;\;\forall\,\alpha\in\Bbb F_7\,$